# Using an AWS CloudWatch alarm to monitor a daily batch job

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a once-daily job that either succeeds or fails. I publish a 0 to a CloudWatch custom metric if it fails, 1 if it succeeds.

How can I create a CloudWatch alarm that monitors this? At the moment, I use "Average < 1 for 1 day", but I worry that if the job runs slightly late, it might trigger an "Insufficient Data" condition.

What is the best period, statistic, etc parameters to use for an alarm to monitor this job?

Comment: why wouldn't you simply let the lambda fail and create a cloudwatch alarm that monitors every minute whether the sum of errors for that lambda > 0. ultimately you want to know about failures but not be bothered about success measures, right?

Comment: I assume OP is talking about AWS Batch, not lambda.